# Install macOS from external hard drive on my Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, install, software-update, external-disk

My Macbook Pro has the prohibitory symbol I am in a remote location where I can't connect to the internet for a long time. I have the macOS Monterey installer saved on an external hard drive. I installed macOS on my external hard drive and it works when I hold <kbd>Option</kbd> and select hard drive to run macOS. Is there a way I can install macOS in recovery mode from the installer on my hard drive to my Macbook Pro with the prohibitory symbol? Or some way from the loaded external hard drive?

Comment: What does "long time" mean? Does this mean you have no access to the internet? Or, does this mean you have access to the internet, but can not stay connected for extended periods?

Comment: If you can boot that Mac from the HD you should just be able to launch the "Install macOS Monterey" application, point it to your MacBook's HD and away you go.

Comment: What exact model of Mac do you have?

Comment: thank you all for taking the time to respond. @SteveChambers - this worked! thanks again.